Implementar algoritmo de programación prospectiva de órdenes en Python utilizando disponibilidad de máquina y restricciones de prioridad en lista?
A partir de estos datos, necesito crear un programa Python que realice una carga utilizando un procedimiento de programación hacia adelante, es decir, una programación hacia adelante donde el objetivo es colocar el pedido en el siguiente espacio disponible.
Tenga en cuenta que el mismo pedido no se puede colocar en varias máquinas al mismo tiempo; en otras palabras, un pedido solo se puede asignar a una máquina por hora.
Estas serían las tablas de datos de entrada proporcionadas al programa:
number_of_machines = 4

#En este caso elegimos 15 pero debería ser un número lo suficientemente grande para cubrir todos los horarios requeridos.
maximum_number_of_hours = 15

# Se proporcionan las horas límite para cada orden de trabajo.
order_and_deadline = [
    ["Order A", 10], 
    ["Order B", 11],
    ["Order C", 13],
    ["Order D", 14]
]

# Se proporcionan las secuencias de prioridades dadas como filas en una hoja de ruta.
routing_sheet = [
    ["Order A", "Order B", "Order C", "Order D"],
    [["Machine 1", 3], ["Machine 3", 2], ["Machine 4", 2], ["Machine 2", 1]],
    [["Machine 2", 2], ["Machine 2", 2], ["Machine 1", 3], ["Machine 3", 2]],
    [["Machine 3", 2], ["Machine 4", 3], ["Machine 3", 2], ["Machine 1", 3]],
    [["Machine 4", 1], ["Machine 1", 1], ["Machine 2", 3], ["Machine 4", 4]],
]

# Crear la fila de encabezado para la tabla de programación
schedule_table = [["Hour"] + [f"Machine {i+1}" for i in range(number_of_machines)] + ["Deadline"]]

Cuanto más a la izquierda se encuentre una columna en la hoja de ruta, mayor será la prioridad del pedido.
La última columna de la hoja de ruta, "Deadline", se completa cuando los pedidos llegan a su hora de finalización.
Ten en cuenta que el mismo pedido no se puede realizar en varias máquinas al mismo tiempo, lo que significa que solo se puede asignar a una máquina por hora.
El procedimiento a seguir es el siguiente:
Primero, localiza la columna de mayor prioridad, en este caso “Order A”, y como la tabla schedule_table está vacía, no habrá ningún tiempo de inactividad.
Luego, coloca todas las Órdenes en las horas y máquinas correspondientes según lo solicitado en la hoja de ruta, y quedaría así:
schedule_table = [
    ['Hour', 'Machine 1', 'Machine 2', 'Machine 3', 'Machine 4', 'Deadline'],
    [1, 'Order A', None, None, None, None],
    [2, 'Order A', None, None, None, None],
    [3, 'Order A', None, None, None, None],
    [4, None, 'Order A', None, None, None],
    [5, None, 'Order A', None, None, None],
    [6, None, None, 'Order A', None, None],
    [7, None, None, 'Order A', None, None],
    [8, None, None, None, 'Order A', None],
    [9, None, None, None, None, None],
    [10, None, None, None, None, 'Order A'],
    [11, None, None, None, None, 'Order B'],
    [12, None, None, None, None, None],
    [13, None, None, None, None, 'Order C'],
    [14, None, None, None, None, 'Order D'],
    [15, None, None, None, None, None]
]

Luego, procedería con la siguiente columna en orden de prioridad, en este caso, "Order B". Pero ahora que los espacios de "Order A" ya están llenos, tendré que intentar colocar "Order B" en los siguientes espacios disponibles. Se vería así:
schedule_table = [
    ['Hour', 'Machine 1', 'Machine 2', 'Machine 3', 'Machine 4', 'Deadline'],
    [1, 'Order A', None, 'Order B', None, None],
    [2, 'Order A', None, 'Order B', None, None],
    [3, 'Order A', None, None, None, None],
    [4, None, 'Order A', None, None, None],
    [5, None, 'Order A', None, None, None],
    [6, None, 'Order B', 'Order A', None, None],
    [7, None, 'Order B', 'Order A', None, None],
    [8, None, None, None, 'Order A', None],
    [9, None, None, None, 'Order B', None],
    [10, None, None, None, 'Order B', 'Order A'],
    [11, None, None, None, 'Order B', 'Order B'],
    [12, None, None, None, None, None],
    [13, None, None, None, None, 'Order C'],
    [14, None, None, None, None, 'Order D'],
    [15, None, None, None, None, None]
]

A continuación, pasaría a la siguiente columna en orden de prioridad, "Order C". Pero como "Order A" y "Order B" ya están colocados, tendré que intentar colocar "Order C" en los siguientes espacios disponibles. Se vería así:
schedule_table = [
    ['Hour', 'Machine 1', 'Machine 2', 'Machine 3', 'Machine 4', 'Deadline'],
    [1, 'Order A', None, 'Order B', 'Order C', None],
    [2, 'Order A', None, 'Order B', 'Order C', None],
    [3, 'Order A', None, None, None, None],
    [4, 'Order C', 'Order A', None, None, None],
    [5, 'Order C', 'Order A', None, None, None],
    [6, 'Order C', 'Order B', 'Order A', None, None],
    [7, None, 'Order B', 'Order A', None, None],
    [8, None, None, 'Order C', 'Order A', None],
    [9, None, None, 'Order C', 'Order B', None],
    [10, None, 'Order C', None, 'Order B', 'Order A'],
    [11, None, 'Order C', None, 'Order B', 'Order B'],
    [12, None, 'Order C', None, None, None],
    [13, None, None, None, None, 'Order C'],
    [14, None, None, None, None, 'Order D'],
    [15, None, None, None, None, None]
]

Finalmente, procedería con la siguiente columna en orden de prioridad, “Order D”. Pero como “Order A”, “Order B” y “Order C” ya están colocados, tendré que intentar colocar “Orden D” en los siguientes espacios disponibles. Se vería así:
schedule_table = [
    ['Hour', 'Machine 1', 'Machine 2', 'Machine 3', 'Machine 4', 'Deadline'],
    [1, 'Order A', 'Order D', 'Order B', 'Order C', None],
    [2, 'Order A', None, 'Order B', 'Order C', None],
    [3, 'Order A', None, 'Order D', None, None],
    [4, 'Order C', 'Order A', 'Order D', None, None],
    [5, 'Order C', 'Order A', None, None, None],
    [6, 'Order C', 'Order B', 'Order A', None, None],
    [7, 'Order D', 'Order B', 'Order A', None, None],
    [8, 'Order D', None, 'Order C', 'Order A', None],
    [9, 'Order D', None, 'Order C', 'Order B', None],
    [10, None, 'Order C', None, 'Order B', 'Order A'],
    [11, None, 'Order C', None, 'Order B', 'Order B'],
    [12, None, 'Order C', None, 'Order D', None],
    [13, None, None, None, 'Order D', 'Order C'],
    [14, None, None, None, 'Order D', 'Order D'],
    [15, None, None, None, 'Order D', None]
]

Después de aplicar una lógica para administrar los espacios disponibles en las máquinas y cómo se asignan los pedidos, la tabla de programación final (que es el resultado esperado) debería verse así:
#Salida correcta:

schedule_table = [
    ['Hour', 'Machine 1', 'Machine 2', 'Machine 3', 'Machine 4', 'Deadline'],
    [1, 'Order A', 'Order D', 'Order B', 'Order C', None],
    [2, 'Order A', None, 'Order B', 'Order C', None],
    [3, 'Order A', None, 'Order D', None, None],
    [4, 'Order C', 'Order A', 'Order D', None, None],
    [5, 'Order C', 'Order A', None, None, None],
    [6, 'Order C', 'Order B', 'Order A', None, None],
    [7, 'Order D', 'Order B', 'Order A', None, None],
    [8, None, None, 'Order C', 'Order A', None],
    [9, None, None, 'Order C', 'Order B', None],
    [10, None, 'Order C', None, 'Order B', 'Order A'],
    [11, None, 'Order C', None, 'Order B', 'Order B'],
    [12, 'Order B', 'Order C', None, 'Order D', None],
    [13, None, None, None, 'Order D', 'Order C'],
    [14, None, None, None, 'Order D', 'Order D'],
    [15, None, None, None, 'Order D', None]
]

Este es mi código, pero esta lógica no funciona porque no organiza bien las ordenes de trabajo en las horas y maquinas correctas:
# Input data
number_of_machines = 4
maximum_number_of_hours = 15

order_and_deadline = [
    ["Order A", 10], 
    ["Order B", 11],
    ["Order C", 13],
    ["Order D", 14]
]

routing_sheet = [
    ["Order A", "Order B", "Order C", "Order D"],
    [["Machine 1", 3], ["Machine 3", 2], ["Machine 4", 2], ["Machine 2", 1]],
    [["Machine 2", 2], ["Machine 2", 2], ["Machine 1", 3], ["Machine 3", 2]],
    [["Machine 3", 2], ["Machine 4", 3], ["Machine 3", 2], ["Machine 1", 3]],
    [["Machine 4", 1], ["Machine 1", 1], ["Machine 2", 3], ["Machine 4", 4]],
]

# Create the header row for the scheduling table
schedule_table = [["Hour"] + [f"Machine {i+1}" for i in range(number_of_machines)] + ["Deadline"]]

# Initialize an empty schedule
schedule = [[None for _ in range(number_of_machines)] for _ in range(maximum_number_of_hours)]

# Mapping machine name to machine index
machine_index_map = {
    "Machine 1": 0,
    "Machine 2": 1,
    "Machine 3": 2,
    "Machine 4": 3,
}

# Assigning orders based on routing sheet
for order_index in range(len(routing_sheet[0])):  # Loop through each order
    order = routing_sheet[0][order_index]
    machines_and_times = routing_sheet[1:][order_index]  # Get routing info for the order

    current_hour = 0
    for machine, duration in machines_and_times:
        machine_idx = machine_index_map[machine]
        for _ in range(duration):  # Schedule for the given duration
            # Find the next available slot for the current machine and hour
            while schedule[current_hour][machine_idx] is not None:
                current_hour += 1
            schedule[current_hour][machine_idx] = order
            current_hour += 1

# Add deadlines to the schedule
for order, deadline in order_and_deadline:
    schedule[deadline - 1].append(order)

# Add schedule to the scheduling table
for hour in range(1, maximum_number_of_hours + 1):
    schedule_table.append([hour] + schedule[hour - 1] + [None] * (len(order_and_deadline) - len(schedule[hour - 1])))

# Final scheduling table output
for row in schedule_table: print(row)

